# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I am newbie , I write 5 line of tkinter but it not runs giving error that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pathparakh/Projects/python/tk/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _tkinter import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

my code is

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
hi = Label(root, text='hi').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

but before 5 hour it runs properly.

Comment: Did you install tk ?

Comment: yes, i installed tk and even run it 5 hours before

Comment: that code can't possibly produce that error, the error message states that you use `from _tkinter import *` (which btw you shouldn't do)

Comment: @PathParakh may be you are now running another python installation

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi `tkinter` is installed on probably all python versions by default (unless you specify not to install it), also the given code couldn't produce that issue anyways (and OP shouldn't use `_modulename` anyways, they are meant to be private)

Comment: i am using python 3.9 and run 'tkinter' not '_tkinter' but it is showing '_tkinter'

Comment: I successfully fix this problem by running

    brew install python-tk@3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully fixed this problem by running the following command:

```
brew install python-tk@3.9
```